# import csv into spss modeler for social network analysis?

Tags: spss, sna, spss-modeler

I want to import my data (csv) into spss modeler for group analysis,but it required fixed width format file,how can I import my data?

thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of an SPSS modeling program that requires a fixed width file for importing, but you can export a fixed width file from Excel.

I'd suggest converting your CSV into an SAV and try importing it instead of the fixed width file.

You can convert CSV to SAV via http://ezcsv2sav.com for free.

Answer (score 0):

I converted my CSV into a trn file and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

From sources insert .var file node, not the fixed width one, and you'll be good. Make sure you set your delimiter and types right, and then you don't need to convert to sav/zsav. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

SPSS Modeler has two different source nodes that will allow you to import text files

1. The [Fixed File](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_18.0.0/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/clementine/fixedfilenode_general.html) node allows you to import text files that have fixed field lengths
2. The [Var. File](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_18.0.0/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/clementine/variablefilenode_general.html) node allows you to import delimited files and to specify the field delimiter used in the file

From your question, it sounds like you may just need to use the [Var. File](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_18.0.0/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/clementine/variablefilenode_general.html) node rather than the [Fixed File](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_18.0.0/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/clementine/fixedfilenode_general.html) node.